# Can we navigate from a ContentPage to a TabbedPage and vice versa in xamarin forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am stuck with the implementation for navigating from a ContentPage to a TabbedPage in xamarin forms development. I could use the navigation property for ContentPage by Navigation.PushAsync()

But, in between few content pages, I have to implement a TabbedPage. What is the best possible approach to solve this ? Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I just answered a question that is so much related here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404956/xamarin-ios-navigate-to-another-view-controller-without-button-on-xamarin