# Xamarin IOS navigate to another view controller without button on xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, xamarin

i start using xamarin to create ios software.
in mainstoryboard, i navigate PageMain view controller to PageTo view controller.
I want navigate from PageMain view controller to PageTo view controller. i use this code and did not auto navigate:

```
var storyBoard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("MainStoryboard", null);
storyBoard.InstantiateViewController ("PageTo");
```

tried this one too but also not auto navigate :

```
PageMainViewController *viewController = segue. PageToViewController;
viewController.delegate = self;
```

tried this one too but also not auto navigate :

```
UIViewController pageto = new PageTo ();
pageto.Transition (PageMain, PageTo);
```

i know it, it easier use button to create push seque to PageTo view controller, but i did not want it.
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing that you can do is push to another view controller...

```
AssignCaseController assignCaseController = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("AssignCaseController") as AssignCaseController;
if (assignCaseController != null)
{
    assignCaseController.CaseID = GetCurrentCaseID();
    this.NavigationController.PushViewController(assignCaseController, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, I just had to do the same.

```
// Clear your notifications and other things

    // Show the controller
    // I am assuming your are using storyboards based in your use of Handle. I am also assuming the identifier in your storyboard for this is set to "WebViewController and its a custom subclass of UIViewController named WebViewController.

    UIStoryboard Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("MainStoryboard", null); // Assume the name of your file is "MainStoryboard.storyboard"

    var webController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("WebViewController") as WebViewController;
    // ... set any data in webController, etc.

    // Make it the root controller for example (the first line adds a paramater to it)
    webController.CaseID = int.Parse(notification.UserInfo["ID"].ToString());
    this.Window.RootViewController = webController;

    // Note* the "Window" should already be set and created because the app is running. No need to remake it.
```